# How can I find out if an Angular 5 application is a single page application or not?

Tags: angular, single-page-application

From what I have [seen](https://www.learnhowtoprogram.com/javascript/angular-extended/multi-page-angular-applications), it is possible to create multi page applications using Angular.

How can I differentiate between a single page application and a multi page application in Angular? Are there certain definite indicators?

Comment: The fact that it loads only one page or several ones? Open your browser dev tools, go in the network panel, and see if it loads only one page or several when you navigate. That said, the page you linked to doesn't describe a multi-page application. It describes a single-page application using routing to change the URL and associate components of the app to URLs. A multi-page application is not that. It's a goold old web site such as wikipedia where, every time you click a link, a complete new page is being loaded and replaces the current page.

Answer (score 0):

The link you provided is talking about creating an SPA (single page application) which has multiple "pages" you can navigate to within the app. Angular handles the routing in this instance, serving up different views as the user clicks links, the address bar in the browser will update accordingly but without reloading the page completely as with a traditional website.

A give away that this routing is occurring  is the address bar which will update as you navigate, for example as per your link, `localhost:4200/albums/1`.

More info and a live example here: https://angular.io/guide/router